# PHP - generate input "x" times

Tags: php, forms, for-loop, input

I'm working on the PHP script where user will write number in the input, than he will click submit and it will generate as many inputs as the user want.

For example, user enter the number 5, it will generate 5 new inputs.

I tried some for cycles and it didn't work.

Thanks for help so much ;)

Comment: *I tried some for cycles and it didn't work* I don't see any attempts neither I don't know what is not working

Comment: You need to provide some code that didn't work for us to help you

Comment: And if they try to add 9223372036854775807 inputs? Might want to give it a bit of thought :)

Comment: if (isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['submit_form_gen'])) {
 $quantity = ($_POST['number']);
 for ($form = "<input type='number'/>"; $form <= $quantity; $form++ ) {
 echo ($form . "<br>");
}
}

Here is the code so far, I know, it's terrible :(

Comment: @DavidPilař Please make use of your edit button: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28570156/edit It isn't useless

Comment: Please use the [**edit** link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28570156/edit) to add details, not comments. And if that's all you want, then `print str_repeat("<input type=number>", $quantity);` would suffice.

Comment: @mario sorry I'm new here I just want to get help with this. Thank you your solution is working. Sorry for being annoying but I need it done with using the for cycle.

Comment: Edit your question. Else nobody will give this a second look. (The issue with your `for` loop is that you're overwriting the `$form` variable - the HTML preset will vanish after the first `$form++` incrementation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you ask

```
if (isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['submit_form_gen'])) { 
    $quantity = ($_POST['number']); 
    for ( $x=0 ; $x<$quantity ; $x++ ) {
        echo '<input type="number" /><br>';
    }
}
```